# Primes of the form $p^2+p+41$

Tags: number-theory

The ten digit prime $1977327019$, which is a prime of the form $a^b+b\cdot c+c^d-2$, with a,b,c,d consecutive primes, seems to be the only prime of this form. It is also a prime such that:

$1977327019^2+1977327019+41$ is also a prime. (Euler polynomial)

can you find primes $p$ greater than $1977327019$ which are such that $p^2+p+41$ is prime. Which is the greatest prime p known such that $p^2+p+41$ is prime?

Answer (score 2):

Finding larger examples is not difficult.  This short PARI/GP program will find primes $p$ of more than $500$ digits such that $p^2 + p + 41$ is also prime:

`forprime(p=10^500,,if(isprime(p^2+p+41),print(p-10^500)))`

After increasing the default stack size a few times, it takes only minutes to output `10023`, meaning that $p=10^{500} + 10023$ is prime and so is $p^2 + p + 41$.

I suspect that this is, for the moment, the largest known number with these properties, but anyone who is so inclined and has a little patience could find a larger one.

Comment: @DietrichBurde [A056561](http://oeis.org/A056561) contains nonnegative integers $n$, not necessarily prime, such that $n^2+n+41$ is prime.  They're quite common; the $10000^\text{th}$ is only $27376$.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful to know.

Answer (score 0):

We have $4(n^2+n+41)=(2n+1)^2+163$, so we can reduce the question to the computation of the Legendre symbol 
$$
\left(\frac{-163}{p}\right)
$$
If $n^2+n+41$ has a prime divisor $p>2$, then $(2n+1)^2+163\equiv 0 \bmod p$, so that $(-163/p)=1$.

But this may not be so helpful for large $n$. We see in Fred's answer that there are larger ones, just by computing.